# Oracle SQL code to list a persons employment events and another 2 columns devoted listing the prior event and date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

So I have a database full of people with employment events and I'm trying to build a report in SQL that will pull the following:

Name, employment event, date of employment event, and the employment event that occurred prior to that event, and date of most recent event.

The data is organized so that each event is a row.  So if I pull the employment history for a participant named John Smith I would get the output (sorted by date of event desc):

```
Name            Event              Date of Event
John Smith      Terminated         5/13/2017
John Smith      Return from Leave  4/13/2017
John Smith      Paid Leave         3/31/2017
John Smith      Hire               1/1/2000
```

My goal is to get the following output:

```
Name            Event              Date of Event     Prior Event          Date of prior event
John Smith      Terminated         5/13/2017         Return from Leave    4/13/2017
John Smith      Return from Leave  4/13/2017         Paid Leave           3/31/2017
John Smith      Paid Leave         3/31/2017         Hire                 1/11/2000
John Smith      Hire               1/1/2000          NULL                 NULL
```

I managed to get a code working that almost does this.

```
select distinct a.ssn, b.name, a.event, a.event_date, 
c.event as prior_event, c.event_date as prior_date
from history a
left join basic_data b
on b.ssn = a.ssn
Left Join
(select distinct c.ssn, c.event_date, c.event
from history c

 ) c
on c.ssn = a.ssn and (a.event > c.event)

order by a.ssn asc, a.event_date desc
```

That gives me this output:

```
Name            Event              Date of Event     Prior Event          Date of prior event
John Smith      Terminated         5/13/2017         Return from Leave     4/13/2017
John Smith      Terminated         5/13/2017         Paid Leave            3/31/2017
John Smith      Terminated         5/13/2017         Hire                  1/1/2000
John Smith      Return from Leave  4/13/2017         Paid Leave            3/31/2017
John Smith      Return from Leave  4/13/2017         Hire                  1/1/2000
John Smith      Paid Leave         3/31/2017         Hire                  1/1/2000
John Smith      Hire               1/1/2000          NULL                  NULL
```

It's showing multiple rows for every event prior to that event instead of just the one before it.  How do I get rid of all of the extra rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`lead()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lead)** analytic function with `order by event_date desc`

```
select h.name as "Name", h.event as "Event", h.event_date as "Date of Event",
       lead(h.event) over (order by event_date desc) as "Prior Event",
       lead(h.event_date) over (order by event_date desc) as "Date of prior event"
  from history h
 order by event_date desc;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf03883211000fb2505f305a7a9f2fed)</kbd>

Comment: Wow!  I never knew about this function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the prior events use `lag()`.  Also, partitioning by the employee is very important:

```
select h.name, h.event, h.event_date,
       lag(h.event) over (partition by h.name order by h.event_date) as prior_event,
       lag(h.event_date) over (order by event_date) as prior_event-date
from history h
order by h.name, event_date desc;
```